# set fallback ip address for hostname in Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dns, hostname

I have 2 machines that switch back and forth between networks.  One network has both configured in the DNS table, so that they can reach each other on that one.  However, on the other network, they don't, but they will have static IP addresses there.

What I would like to do is configure both machines to FIRST query the DNS for an IP address when attempting to resolve a hostname, and, if that fails, THEN go to a static hosts file (i.e. `/etc/hosts`) to find an IP address for it.  Can this be done, both on Win7 and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is change the hostname resolution order.

On Ubuntu, try looking in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. There should be a line

```
hosts:    files dns
```

If you change that to

```
hosts:    dns files
```

it will try a DNS query first, and then go to `/etc/hosts` if the query fails.

(source: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

On Windows, try changing the settings in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\ServiceProvider
```

Change `HostsPriority` to be greater than `DnsPriority` (I'd recommend making it `2002`).

(source: http://www.speedguide.net/articles/host-resolution-priority-tweak-1130)